# How to fix "query does not include the specified expression 'credit usd' as part of an aggregate function"?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm try to select **"max(TxnDate) as txDate, [account name dr], [credit usd]"** and I got an error "query does not include the specified expression 'credit usd' as part of an aggregate function" in excel VBA programming but in work find when I tried in SQL sever or PHPMyadmin

I'm working on MSExcel 2013 with VBA programming

```
SELECT max(TxnDate) as txDate, [account name dr], [credit usd] from 
   (
       SELECT t.TxnDate, t.[account name dr], t.[credit usd] FROM 
       ( 
           select [account name dr], max([credit usd]) as max_c from [FT_Pure$] GROUP BY [account name dr]
       ) as a INNER JOIN [FT_Pure$] as t on (t.[account name dr] = a.[account name dr] and t.[credit usd] = max_c)
   ) as ta group by ta.[account name dr]
```

I expect the output should list of **txDate, account_name_dr and Credit_Usd**

Here is the error message:

[image: Error messsage]

Comment: What does the error message say - to you?

Comment: You need to add `credit usd` to the `group by` clause. With that said, I think your query could be much shorter...  Sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: I got a message error "Your query does not include the specified expression 'credit usd' as part of an aggregate function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer GROUP BY clause is missing [credit usd] which you have in the outer select along with [account name dr].

Just add it in:

```
SELECT max(TxnDate) as txDate, [account name dr], [credit usd] from 
   (
       SELECT t.TxnDate, t.[account name dr], t.[credit usd] FROM 
       ( 
           select [account name dr], max([credit usd]) as max_c from [FT_Pure$] GROUP BY [account name dr]
       ) as a INNER JOIN [FT_Pure$] as t on (t.[account name dr] = a.[account name dr] and t.[credit usd] = max_c)
   ) as ta group by ta.[account name dr], [credit usd]
```

Comment: Such a great answer, it help me. But I still not sure whether why it's worked properly in SQL (PHPmyadmin) but return an error in VBA Excel?

Comment: It works now both VBA and SQL base on above answer but I just wondered why this error occurred?

Comment: It may be that PHPmyadmin is a bit more forgiving  than Excel VBA is willing to be. I'd have thought it should return an error in both situations though as the error is being returned from MySQL presumably.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the most recent row for each account, then aggregation is not what comes to mind.  You can use filtering:

```
select t.*
from [FT_Pure$] t
where t.TxnDate = (select max(t2.TxnDate)
                   from [FT_Pure$] t2
                   where t2.[account name dr] = t.[account name dr]
                  );
```

Comment: Seem like affected with performance when I tried this Query. And another one is that, its not provide proper result as I expected. I expected to get (Account name dr) with Highest (Credit Usd) because we have many account name dr (Duplicated ACCOUNT NAME DR)  with different Credit USD.

Comment: @KryChulsa . . . Your question is:  "I'm try to select "max(TxnDate) as txDate, [account name dr], [credit usd]".